# rest every two rows of the same column in sql and and convert the result in seconds

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

I need help with my Hive table .

```
   DATE               |    ID     |    RESTDATESINSECONDS     

 2019-03-28 10:05:27        1             (2019-03-28 10:05:38)-(2019-03-28 10:05:27)
 2019-03-28 10:05:38        1             (2019-03-28 10:14:14)- (2019-03-28 10:05:38)
 2019-03-28 10:14:14        1             (2019-03-28 10:14:16) -(2019-03-28 10:14:14)
 2019-03-28 10:14:16        1             (2019-03-28 10:14:46) -(2019-03-28 10:14:16)
 2019-03-28 10:14:46        1             (2019-03-28 10:15:30) -(2019-03-28 10:15:30)
 2019-03-28 10:15:30        1                """
     """                    """              """
```

I have two hundred thousand rows. I would like to return this as:

```
   DATE               |    ID     |    RESTDATESINSECONDS     

 2019-03-28 10:05:27        1             11
 2019-03-28 10:05:38        1             516
 2019-03-28 10:14:14        1             2
 2019-03-28 10:14:16        1             30
 2019-03-28 10:14:46        1             44
 2019-03-28 10:15:30        1             ""
```

I have tried all kinds of parenthesis and counts, but everything I try throws different errors for syntax! Does anyone have any ideas?

Many Thanks :)

Comment: (1) Are you using SQL Server or HQL?  (2) What is the datatype of `RESTDATESINSECONDS`?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff ! I am using HQL and the format of "RESTDATESINSECONDS"  will be int. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte_test_table
as
(select * from
  ( values('2019-03-28 10:05:27',1)
         ,('2019-03-28 10:05:38',1)
         ,('2019-03-28 10:14:14',1)
         ,('2019-03-28 10:14:16',1)
         ,('2019-03-28 10:14:46',1)
         ,('2019-03-28 10:15:30',1)
  ) as t([Date],ID)
)

select ID, [Date]
,datediff(ss,[Date],LAG ([Date], 1, [Date]) over (partition by ID order by [Date] desc)) as RESTDATESINSECONDS
from cte_test_table
order by [Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the rows from which you want the time difference are not guaranteed to be consecutive, you can do it with this (which works in any case):

```
select 
  t.id,
  t.date,
  datediff(
    s, 
    t.date, 
    (select min(date) from tablename where id = t.id and date > t.date)
  ) restdateinseconds
from tablename t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e330134d19c079c03ad8837b3141e3e1).
Results:

```
> id | date                | restdateinseconds
> -: | :------------------ | ----------------:
>  1 | 28/03/2019 10:05:27 |                11
>  1 | 28/03/2019 10:05:38 |               516
>  1 | 28/03/2019 10:14:14 |                 2
>  1 | 28/03/2019 10:14:16 |                30
>  1 | 28/03/2019 10:14:46 |                44
>  1 | 28/03/2019 10:15:30 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()` function to get next row `date` and `unix_timestamp()` to convert dates to seconds, then subtract:

```
with test_data as (
select stack(6,
'2019-03-28 10:05:27',
'2019-03-28 10:05:38',
'2019-03-28 10:14:14',
'2019-03-28 10:14:16',
'2019-03-28 10:14:46',
'2019-03-28 10:15:30') as `date`
)

select `date`, unix_timestamp(lead(`date`) over(order by `date`)) - unix_timestamp(`date`) as restdateinseconds
  from test_data;
```

Returns:

```
date                 restdateinseconds
2019-03-28 10:05:27    11   
2019-03-28 10:05:38    516  
2019-03-28 10:14:14    2    
2019-03-28 10:14:16    30   
2019-03-28 10:14:46    44   
2019-03-28 10:15:30    NULL
```